# Centos, ZPanel and Cloudflare DNS recorddns error

Tags: dns, centos, cloudflare

I am stuck in a problem. I have a VPS which gave me a dedicated IPv6 address and a shared IPv4 address. I have tunneled it and installed zpanel on my centos server. Now I can access zpanel from 31.220.48.155:22277 and I have also set up a new domain in zpanel. I added 31.220.48.155:22277 in cloudflare A record but it wont allow saying "You entered '31.220.48.155:22277' which is not a valid IP address." I am stuck. Please Help...

Comment: Mods, do not migrate to ServerFault. The user has cross-posted the question already. Users here, vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

'31.220.48.155:22277 is not a valid IPv4 address & you would put in 31.220.48.155. It looks like you're trying to add a port number after the IP address & that is not correct.